# Git Pull Request no changes but git diff show changes

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have an issue with my branches

#### *Introduction*

I have 3 branches on my project : Dev, Main & Staging

On **Dev** branch we add new features, on **Main** branch we fix bugs, on **Staging** we deploy for testing.

When a bug PullRequest is completed on **Main** branch, we make a PullRequest **Main** -> Dev** to keep up to date the **Dev** branch.
When a new feature is developed, a PullRequest is complete on **Dev** branch.

When we want to deploy all the new features, we make a PullRequest **Dev -> Main**, and then a PullRequest **Main -> Staging**. Finally we deploy the content of **Staging** branch

#### *Problem*

When I compare manually my branches **Dev** and **Main**, I see there are differences : in **Dev** branch some files appeared in a folder, but it were moved to another folder before in a previous commit on **Main** branch.

When I make `git diff Main..Dev`, I see there are same differences than above.

Normally, at this moment, this two branches have to be at the same state. So I made a PullRequest **Main -> Dev** to give to branch **Dev** the correct state (**Main** state) : but it say that there are no changes on my PullRequest.

#### *Question*

How can I properly give to **Dev** branch the current state of my **Main** branch ?

Thank you

Comment: ", I see there are differences.", could you tell us a little bit of **what kind** of differences you see?

Comment: I update the question to add more precision for sentence ", I see there are differences."

Comment: How does a pull request end? Merge, rebase, or squash and merge?

Comment: if you want the exact same state you don"t want to merge you want to force the branch to be the same. you can have reach this state by having fixed some conflict on merge leading to this difference, after that on merge you will get this resolution.

Comment: @matt : It's "Merge (No fast-forward)"

Comment: @Ôrel : How can I force the branch to be the same ?

Comment: What you are describing is what I would expect to see if you tried to merge Main to Dev twice in a row. They differ, but there is nothing to do.

Comment: "How can I force the branch to be the same" That is not what a merge is at all. Merges don't cause two branches to represent the same state of the project. If you wanted Dev to be absolutely identical to Main you would branch Dev off of Main!

Comment: @matt
I don't want that Dev to be identical to Main (with same commit, etc..).
I just want that Dev have the same files than Main just at this moment (not every time). 

I have one solution : copy all files of Main branch, checkout to Dev, paste all files. But I don't like this solution, I would like to know if there is another cleaner solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What might have happened

As @matt said in the comments, this is probably the result of a previous merge, where the conflict might have been resolved without moving the files. Now, when you merge again, Git thinks it's already handled that renaming so it doesn't have to deal with it. You could confirm this theory by looking at the commit history since the last merge point: are the renames before or after that?

#### How to merge `Main` in and force `Dev` to take the state of `Main`

If, at this point, you want to throw away the current state of `Dev` and make it exactly the state of `Main`, and you want to do with with a merge operation, I would use the `ours` strategy. I'm not sure you can do this via a PR, you'll probably have to do it on your PC and push, I hope your workflow allows this!

Unfortunately, you cannot directly do `git merge -s theirs Main` from `Dev`, that would be too simple. You have to do `git merge -s ours Dev` from `Main` to create the merge commit you want on `Dev`:

```sh
git checkout Main
git merge -s ours Dev  # this "merges" Dev in but ignores all its changes
# don't push this!
git checkout Dev
git merge Main  # this should be a fast-forward merge
# now you can push Dev
```

And you can clean up your sandbox when you're done, by bringing `Main` back to where it was, since that merge was intended for `Dev`:

```
git checkout Main
git reset --hard origin/Main
```

#### What if I want the renames from `Main`, but not lose the other changes in `Dev`?

In this case I think you will need to do some manual work. If the renames are indeed before the previous merge, and the merge that brought those commits into the history of `Dev` was resolved without applying the renames, you need to recreate the renames again on the `Dev` branch, possibly by hand.

I don't imagine you have the option of going back to that earlier merge and redo it correctly, but if you could, that might be the cleanest option.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works !
I don't know the parameters "-s ours" of the merge command, thank for the discovery !